# Help regarding heading and page numbers

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

[image]

I want to place the heading in the middle and the page number below in Latex. Please suggest how to do it.

I am using the following coding.

```
\chapter{$\Lambda$-Modules}\ref{ch:prili}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Chapter
\ref{ch:prili}:~Preliminaries}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: Please provide us with some form of [minimal document](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr) package provides a lot of options for customizing headers and footers, including control over the location of page numbers. Having the page number at the bottom and a centered header text could go like this, for a simple example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chead{Header text} % Can also use \lhead or \rhead

\cfoot{\thepage} % Can also use \lfoot or \rfoot

\begin{document}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`fancyhdr` is the easiest way to go.  `\usepackage{google}` for more info.  i think you want something like (not tested)

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\chaptername \thechapter. \chaptermark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```